# Div's overlap when using fixed positioning in responsive layout.

Tags: html, css, position, hide, fixed

I am creating a website with a responsive layout.

I have two columns: Sidebar and Content.

The sidebar has 20% width and has a fixed position whereas the Content has 80% width with static position.

How do I stop the content from hiding under the Sidebar when the screen size is reduced?

Comment: You could use media queries to change it from `fixed` to `static` for the smaller sizes

Comment: "responsive layout...fixed position"; if it's responsive it's not fixed & if it's fixed it's not responsive... i would make the css static & the fix with js with a resize event handler

Comment: I don't agree with you @mikakun, We can do both.

Comment: Also, surely the content is hiding under the sidebar on any size screen? Given that `fixed` takes it out of the document flow, the 20% and 80% aren't relevant to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
overflow:hidden
```

Try adding that

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with media queries

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make something `fixed`, it's taken out of the document flow.  As such, the content should be hiding underneath the sidebar irrespective of whether the two columns widths are set to `20%` and `80%`.

You can see that here:  http://jsbin.com/OQOSEZoF/3/edit (the words '80%' don't show).

So you will probably need to set `padding-left: 20%` on the content `<div>` anyway.  That may solve your problem on it's own.

If however, if you have other content down the page, such as a footer that is being overlapped by the fixed div, you could use media queries to change styles depending on the screen size.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
  #sidebar {
    position: static;
  }
  #content {
    padding-left: 0; 
  }
}
```

See the demo here: http://jsbin.com/OQOSEZoF/6/edit

When you resize the result to less than 500 pixels, the text in the footer becomes visible because the sidebar switches to static.